# Can't connect to django server in browser

Tags: django, python-2.7

Tried running it from local host but  in cmd prompt its fine as i see "Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.". But not connecting in browser. Also tried telnet to connect to that port, but failed. what could be the reason? can't be a  proxy as even telnet is not workiing

[image]

Comment: U have missed the port number!

Comment: This is probably the worst question I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 1):

Add the port number, probably 8000, after the url in the browser: http://127.0.0.1:8000.